# `DropdownButtonFormField` not working when clicking outside the scope

Tags: flutter

### Info

I am just working on the billing address form, but I am not able to guess what is happening.

I am able to populate the countries data in the dropdown. But when I click outside the dropdown means not selecting any country then I am getting an error.

### Code

```dart
class BillingAddressForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BillingAddressFormState createState() => _BillingAddressFormState();
}

class _BillingAddressFormState extends State<BillingAddressForm> {
  String? country;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          buildCountryFormField(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  DropdownButtonFormField buildCountryFormField() {
    return DropdownButtonFormField(
      isDense: true,
      iconSize: 0.0,
      value: country,
      items: ['Country 1', 'Country 2', 'Country 3', 'Country 4']
          .map((String country) {
        return new DropdownMenuItem(
          value: country,
          child: Text(country),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (newValue) {
        setState(() => country = newValue);
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Country",
        hintText: "Enter your country",
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon:
            CustomSuffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/location-point-icon.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Steps to reproduce

- Click on the country dropdown.
- Don't select any country just tap outside.

### Error

[image]

Comment: This code by itself works fine. It appears we’re missing something since the error involves a Future that isn’t in the code snippet.

Comment: Yeah exactly. There is no way I can handle the null value in the `onChange` method.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this? Or this is fixed in latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long struggle, I am able to solve the problem.

I just upgraded the Flutter SDK from `2.0` to `2.2`. And now the error is gone, I think the problem is in the lower version of the Flutter SDK.

Hope this will save some's time.